# Add Url Rule to Azure Application Gateway from a different ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-rm-template

I have an resource group ARM template that I use to create an application gateway that is configured for url routing. It sends traffic to different Web Apps in that resource group based on url path rules. I deploy the base resource group ARM template, and then each web app has its own ARM template that setups a Web App on an App Service Plan. I am trying to figure out how to add a rule to an existing Url Path Map on an Application Gateway without defining the whole application gateway in every template. This way, I can simply add web apps and have them "register" on to the application gateway with a particular path rule.

I considered doing a linked template where my base template would have all of the shared resources (databases, app service plan, and app gateway), but even with a linked template, I don't think I can add a rule to the application gateway.

**Update**
So I modified my template by adding a reference to the existing application gateway, and then adding variables for the new BackEndPoolAddress and new Path Rule. It ends up like this (abbreviated to only relevant parts):

```
 "variables": {
    "appGateway": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/', 'appGateWay-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)), '2017-06-01')]",
    "pathRule": {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('websiteName'), '- RoutingRule')]",
      "properties": {
        "paths": [
          "[parameters('routingRule')]"
        ],
        "backendAddressPool": {
          "id": "[concat(variables('appGateway').id, '/backendAddressPools/',parameters('websiteName'), 'BackEndPool')]"
        },
        "backendHttpSettings": {
          "id": "[variables('appGateway').backendHttpSettingsCollection[0]]"
        }
      }
    },
    "backendPool": {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('websiteName'), 'BackEndPool')]",
      "properties": {
        "IpAddress": "[reference(variables('webSiteName')).defaultHostName]"
      }
    }
  },
 "resources": [
  ...
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('appGateway').name]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "backendAddressPools": "[concat(variables('appGateway').backendAddressPools, variables('backendPool'))]",
        "urlPathMaps": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('appGateway').urlPathMaps[0]]",
            "pathRules": "[concat(variables('appGateway').urlPathMaps[0].pathRules, variables('pathRule'))]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
```

However I get a template validation error saying I can't use the Reference function in the Variables section. If I don't add it in the variables section, how can I build the correct paths for the pool and pathRule in my variables section?

Comment: Hi Mike. Can you please share some insights as to how you got it working via nested template route. I am trying to achieve the below using nested template:
Have a separate template file for each application and call all of them from the main.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Avi I actually switched from ARM to CLI recently, so I don't have that code anymore, but it was really easy to do with the CLI because it is idempotent. I will add an answer below showing how I update my load balancer with a simple Azure CLI script that runs each time my deployment runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using the `reference()` function, array manipulation and nested templates (might work even without those, worst case you will need them). example:

```
"outputs": {
    "httpListeners": {
        "type": "array",
        "value": "[reference('application_gateway_id', '2018-08-01', 'Full').properties.httpListeners]"
    }
}
```

Will return you array or httpListeners. you can get all the relevant application gateway properties and add new (additional) properties with the `concat()` and assign the result to the property (properties):

```
"httpListeners": "[concat(reference('application_gateway_id', '2018-08-01', 'Full').properties.httpListeners, variables('newListener'))]"
```

you just need to make sure 2 deployments dont start at the same time, one might overwrite the other

Comment: Ended up having to go with the nested template route, but this got me pointed in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I finally ended up with using the Azure CLI. This script is idempotent and runs during my release process.

```bsh
echo "Logging into AKS Cluster"
az aks get-credentials --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP_NAME --name $AKSNAME

echo "Get the created service's ip address"
SERVICEIP=$(kubectl get service --namespace $AKSNAMESPACE $APPNAME-service -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}")


echo "Creating backend pool - IP $SERVICEIP"
az network application-gateway address-pool create \
  --gateway-name $APPGATEWAYNAME \
  --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP_NAME \
  --name "$APPNAME-pool" \
  --servers $SERVICEIP

echo "Creating probe"
az network application-gateway probe create \
    --gateway-name $APPGATEWAYNAME \
    --name "$APPNAME-probe" \
    --path $APPPROBE \
    --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP_NAME \
    --protocol Http \
    --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP_NAME \
    --host-name-from-http-settings true 

echo "Creating HTTP Settings"
az network application-gateway http-settings create \
    --gateway-name $APPGATEWAYNAME \
    --name "$APPNAME-settings" \
    --port 80 \
    --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP_NAME \
    --host-name-from-backend-pool \
    --probe "$APPNAME-probe" \
    --protocol Http



echo "Creating URL Path Map"
az network application-gateway url-path-map rule create \
    --gateway-name $APPGATEWAYNAME \
    --name "$APPNAME-rule" \
    --paths $RULEPATH \
    --path-map-name $RULENAME \
    --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP_NAME \
    --http-settings "$APPNAME-settings" \
    --address-pool "$APPNAME-pool"
```